# NodeJS stucked at loading and cant display image

Tags: javascript, node.js

When running the below code and accessing `http://localhost:3000/about.html` directly, the html page displays the alt text i placed in the img tag

```
const http = require('http');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const url = require('url');

const port = 3000;


// Access it by http://localhost:3000
const server = http.createServer((request, result) => {
    if (request.url.match(/\/$/)) {
        fs.readFile('./index.html', (error, data)=> {
            if (error) {
                result.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type':'text/html'});
                return result.end();
            }
            result.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/html'});
            result.write(data);
            result.end();
    
        })
    } else if (request.url.match(/\/index.html$|\/about.html$/)) {
        let q = url.parse(request.url, true);
        let filename =  "." + q.pathname;
        fs.readFile(filename, (error, data)=> {
            if (error) {
                result.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type':'text/html'});
                return result.end();
            }
            result.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/html'});
            result.write(data);
            result.end();

        });
    } else {
        fs.readFile('./index.html', (error, data)=> {
            if (error) {
                result.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type':'text/html'});
                return result.end();
            }
            result.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/html'});
            result.write(data);
            result.end();
    
        });
    }


});

server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at port ${port}`);
});
```

However if i run the below code and access `http://localhost:3000/about.html` directly, i can see the image directly. Whats the difference?

```
const server = http.createServer((request, result) => {
    
        let q = url.parse(request.url, true);
        let filename =  "." + q.pathname;
        fs.readFile(filename, (error, data)=> {
            if (error) {
                result.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type':'text/html'});
                return result.end();
            }
            result.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/html'});
            result.write(data);
            result.end();

    });


});
```

All the requires and listen port is the same for the code. Below is the HTML code for about.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>About</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="./image/frog.jpg" title="Cute Image of frog" alt="Cute Image of frog">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In your original code the request for the image is answered by returning the index.html in the `else {`-part and therefore your browser displays the alt-text as no valid image-data could be displayed.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Why isnt the second if-else block executed since it match the regex?

Comment: Oh wait is it because the <img> tag is ran as another request to the server?

Comment: Exactly! Every image, every JavaScript-file, every CSS-file, ... results in a new request from browser to the corresponding webserver.